# how to connect with each other images in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem in flutter. About the image.
I have illustration images of body parts.
I want to connect these together and show them.

This is because I want to interact with each other, such as turning on lights when touching each area.

I used it at first. Just use "align"
However, it is placed differently from device to device.

How can I solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s40I.png)

Comment: If your image parts is transparent, you can try `Stack` and `Positioned`

Comment: Thank you, but I'm having another problem.
I want to show the same on a different size screen, but it's not. What should I do?

Comment: Try to make use of `MediaQuery` to get screen size then use `SizedBox` to adjust height and width depending on screen size. Then probably you also have to use the `BoxFit` to fit the image.